# Identify this USB cable

Tags: cable

I need some help identifying a cable that I found in my house. I hope this is the right place to ask it. It said computer hardware, so a cable would count right?

Anyway, I took a couple of pictures and hope someone can identify it. I thought it was micro USB, but that doesn't seem correct when I compared it to the pictures I saw on the web. The other end of the cable is just a regular USB that plugs into any USB port on a computer.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Here is the bottom part:

[image]

Here is the top part:

[image]

Here is my attempt at taking a pic of the inside:

[image]

Comment: At first instance it looks like Mini-USB cable but it is not. Looks like some sort of proprietary cable with USB interface. Any brand/company names stamped on the cable?

Comment: I vaguely recall seeing similar cables off VERY cheap chinese made cameras. It MIGHT be a mini A

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a I-USB7 cable.

It acts just like a normal usb cable, but the connector is shaped differently than the standard mini connector.

It was commonly used on Pentax Cameras
http://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/pentax-beginners-corner-q/136826-pentax-usb-lead.html
[http://www.amazon.com/Pentax-I-USB7-Cable-Digital-Cameras/dp/B0000C4G3G](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000C4G3G)

---

It may also be a CB-USB7 cable which was used on Olympus cameras. However CB-USB7 were thinner if I remember correctly.
http://www.getolympus.com/us/en/usb-download-cable-cb-usb7.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. So this cable can only be used with Pentax cameras or does any other device has this type of connector? I don't have a Pentax camera, so I still can't figure out what gadget this cable came with.

Comment: Other vendors like cannon, and olympus also used proprietary connectors for a time. I've also seen camcorders that used either the I-USB7 or the CB-USB7.

Comment: I've seen either similar or the same connector on Canon, Nikon, and Kodak cameras. All were slightly different, and, without seeing it in person, I couldn't tell you which it was from. It could also be from another device from an Asian manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a proprietary connector used primarily for Digital Cameras. Its a  UC-E6
connector - I have one on the data cable connector for my Pentax K5. The connector also fits a small HD cube camera that I picked up on AliBaba a couple years back.
They are difficult to source.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common kind of cable, I think the others have explained it, but you find it fits in camera's, nook, ps3 pad possibly. Just see if it fits, and then you'll know.